# How to output class using Simple html DOM

Tags: php, dom, frameworks

I have a little problem.

```
    $result = array();
    $html = file_get_html('http://site.com/page.html');
    $content = $html->find('#details');
    foreach($content as $value) {
        $result['discription'] = what?
    }
```

How can I display all data from the class using a simple html DOM framework?

Comment: elaborate more please

Comment: @user1708762, I need to take data from html page. There is a class - #details. I need to display all the information out of him. (Sorry for my bad english)